# Notepad++ replace and exclude certain column

Tags: notepad++

Hi I'm totally new with notepad++ and I need some help with replace function in regex.

What I'm trying to change is something like this

from

> 640F0000 00000000 00000F01
>
> 640F0000 00000000 00002A01
>
> 640F0000 00000000 00008501
>
> 640F0000 00000000 00002201

to

> 640F0000 00000000 00000F**2**1
>
> 640F0000 00000000 00002A**2**1
>
> 640F0000 00000000 000085**2**1
>
> 640F0000 00000000 000022**2**1

In search i get good result with ""640F0000 00000000 0000..01" but whenever i replace with ""640F0000 00000000 0000..21" it will replace with the .. sign with it.

Any advice or guide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to replace everything in this column with `2`?

Comment: Later on i need to change it to letter + number on it depend on files i need to edit.

Comment: Find: `01$` Replace: `21`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

- Find what: `^(640F0000 00000000 0.+)(01)$`
- Replace with:\121
- Search mode: `Regular expression`

Comment: That's what i'm looking for! Thank you!

If let's say i need to change from 01 to FF, is it replace it with \1FF ?

Comment: @ECYL Yes, you can replace it with \1FF. If the question has been answered satisfactorily, You can mark it as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).